Permission handler doesn't work with new android version
I just created a new app with Flutter 3.22.1 and Dart SDK version: 3.4.1.
I'm using permission_handler 11.3.1 package to get storage permission but the pop up to allow the permission never shows, it doesn't log any errors in debug console. I've printed the result of .request() function its show PermissionStatus.denied
here is my manifest file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <application
        android:label="xlsxtosqlite"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

Flutter code:
Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    if (await permission.isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      var result = await permission.request();
      print(result);
      return result == PermissionStatus.granted;
    }
  }

calling the function:
await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)

my compilesdkversion is 34 and I'm running it on emulator api 34

Did you try to uninstall the application and re-install? It could be that you previously permanently denied it

yes i have, i also did flutter clean

i tried it on old android version(8) it work, doesn't work with latest android version that is 14

await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)

Permission.storage is deprecated for Android 13 (API 33) and above and always returns PermissionStatus.denied
Instead use Permission.photos, Permission.video, Permission.audio or Permission.manageExternalStorage
for Android below 13 (API 33), the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are requested (depending on the definitions in the AndroidManifest.xml) file.
here's link to all possible permissions in manifest file
add permissions as per your requirements
